# jQuery Auto refresh div/span every 5 sec

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh

i have a content to display score in html. Here is the example

```
<div id="homescore">0</div>
<div id="awayscore">0</div>
```

I want auto refresh div homescore and awayscore every 5 second without php. Is it possible

Comment: use [.setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `setTimeout` function.

Define a function `refreshDivContent` which will take your div id that needs to be refreshed.Populate div from ajax call or whatever source you are doing(I have shown an ajax example) and then call this `refreshDivContent` again inside `setTimeout`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var refreshDivContent = function(divid) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "path",
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#' + divid).html(data);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        refreshDivContent(divid);
                    }, 5000);
                }
            });
    };

refreshDivContent('homescore');  // Use it 

});
```